# Angular cant find local image on phones

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, image, windows-phone

I'm trying to load an image from Angular into an img tag. The image loads find when I type the full path like 'ImageMap.jpg' directly into the src field in html. But when I set the value in Angular it doesnt work, it can't find the image. This happens on all devices I tested on, I included a screenshot of the WP emulator at the bottom of the post.
I built the apps using Cordova.

This works

```
    <img ng-src="ImageMap.jpg"  class="stretch" ng-show="true">
```

This does not

```
    <img ng-src="{{ gifSource }}"  class="stretch" ng-show="true">
```

I set the value in the first line of the controller

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
    $scope.gifSource = "ImageMap.jpg";
```

This works fine in Chrome, but does not in for example the WP emulator/device.

I added this line in my HTML to check the path gets set, which it does. The file is in the root folder along with index.html

```
 <b> Path: {{ gifSource }}</b>
```

[image: WP Emulator]

Comment: Might be a silly question, but have you tried testing it in IE? Probably closer to the rendering/js engines used on WP than Chrome is.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 and for some reason IE doesnt work anymore, it just doesn't launch :p 
But it's the same on an Android emulator

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I fixed that after defined an absolute path of application as value and put that value into "ng-src" attribute to reach needed image.

For example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myCtrl']);

myApp.value("basePath", "http://localhost/my/path/images/");
```

and then in controller:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'ngRoute', 'basePath', function($scope, basePath){

    // Use basePath value to get url and concatenate it with image
    $scope.basePath = basePath + 'myimage.png';

  }]);
```

In this way you can pass your value within whole application, you just need to change image name in order to use different images.